# What does P>0.05; 0.025 < P ≤ 0.05 ; Yes, 0.01 < P ≤ 0.025 and, P ≤ 0.01 mean ? hypothesis testing p-values

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value

I'm learning for my exam which is tomorrow and in the practice exam there are a lot of questions where you can choose between those p-values, but what do they mean?

an example question

A test is standardized in a way that μ = 100. The population variance is unknown. In a sample of 31 persons we find x = 103 and s = 6.28. The research question is whether the sample is drawn from a population with a mean score greater than 100. Can the H0 be rejected with ↵ = 0.05?
a. No,P>0.05
b. Yes, 0.025 < P  0.05
 c. Yes, 0.01 < P ≤ 0.025 
d. Yes, P ≤ 0.01

i just don't understand for what they all stand. how can i interpret them?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a z-test for me. z=(x-mu)/s*sqrt(n). Here it is (103-100)/6.28*sqrt(31). Than you look if the critical z values are higher or smaller than those for your hypothesis. Good luck for your exam.

Comment: Should actually be a t-test since population variance is unknown and sample size is relatively small.